# installing vista on a laptop

Tags: windows-vista, laptop

I have a laptop which has a vista setup kit partition with drivers. After i buy it i had to do the next, next routine to install vista from those partition to the laptop.

Now, if I wish to reinstall Vista but to use the same partition as a source...how can I do it?

it is about a Toshiba satellite A300D

UPDATE:

1) I've tried [HDD Recovery Procedure](http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/kb0/HTD9102IR0000R01.htm) but i don't have Toshiba HDD Recovery in the menu, maybe because I've installed Windows 7.

2) also, I've tried to boot holding down the 0 button ([this method](http://futureshopforums.com/t5/Computer-Services/my-recovery-disk-is-not-work-how-to-recover-from-the-hard-drive/m-p/79025)) but i get no HDD Recovery Mode

I'm sure that the partition with the prebuilt MS Vista is on HDD and intact. All I need is to activate it and boot from it.

Answer (score 1):

The "next next" routine is the final stage of the OEM install routing, so Windows was probably already almost installed and was just asking for confirmation of your internationalisation settings and other such. There may be a "recovery partition" that you can rebuild from though it is getting common for this not to be the case and instead for you to be provided with a "rescue/restore" disk that contains the OEM copy of Windows with the extra specific drivers needed for the machine's manufacturer's range slipstreamed in. Some manufacturers will actually include a physical disk in the box when you buy the laptop, others will include a copy on the hard-drive and expect you to burn it to a DVD yourself.

The intended procedure for reinstalling a laptop back to factory settings is therefore manufacturer/model specific so for more specific answers you will need to include the make+model of your machine in your question.

Comment: it's about a toshiba a300d. ty for your replay